# Хранение статей

Tags: php, laravel

Возник вопрос с сохранением статей. Допустим мне нужно сохранить статью в БД. В статье много тегов: все возможные выделения, цитирования и тд и тп.

Тут и вопросы, правильно ли всю статью сохранять в БД (со всеми нужными тегами) и затем выводить на страницу без экранизации?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В общем случае - правильно.

Если статьи редактирует админ, то он как бы и так имеет доступ, у него резона ломать сайт нету. То есть от него защищать текст нет смысла.

Если статьи добавляют пользователи, то никакого HTML, а [Markdown](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown)